# What is the most efficient approach about dependencies versions?

Tags: version-control, versioning, packages

Recently I had many problems opening old projects, which had all dependencies in `package.json` defined with **^** x.y.z. When I pull the code and run `npm install` the dependencies are installed but I will for sure have some problem with some package that is related to versions.

My question is if having a `package.json` like the following without **^** is not better than having the default way with **^** x.y.z

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "react-hook-form": "7.40.0",
  ...
}
```

Also, for all the companies out there, is not better for them to lock the package version to avoid those problems and have control over what is installed into their projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if having a package.json like the following without ^ is not better than having the default way with ^ x.y.z

In my humble opinion. **Absolutely**. You shouldn't leave it to the wild (and hope for the best) when it comes to the right and precise dependencies that make your code work.

Think about all the "confidence" you have built around those dependencies. It goes from the confidence of code doing what it's expected to do<sup>1</sup>, up to the confidence you provide to your stakeholders (milestones achievements, sense of progress, attachment to the planning, etc).

If you can't guarantee that the code on production behaves exactly the same way then the code you have built and executed hundred times in your IDE, then all that confidence banishes. And doesn't matter if tests pass because different dependencies might result in different corner cases you might be unable to reproduce in your IDE. And vice-versa.

---

<sup>1: When you choose a dependency on its version x.y.z you are also choosing its drawbacks (say bugs, say design flaws) and limitations. The confidence is built upon them too.</sup>

Comment: Locking in the package.json would also impact when we have different OS's for development and production, is that true? I say that because I had some problems with packages when going from Windows for development and Linux for production, and I heard also that the lock files doesn't work well when we are going from a different OS

Comment: Honestly, I have never developed anything on Windows. My local env is always in the same O.S than production (for obvious reasons). I don't know why packages would behave in different ways on Windows and Linux. I can be wrong but I think JS is cross platform. Browsers and engines might not if they were compiled to native. Maybe the issue are not the packages, but the runtime (browser, VM) Sadly, I can't help you with that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, locking packages to specific versions is important, but package managers often use lock files for this purpose. NPM uses [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-lock-json).

The package.json file specifies which versions *should* work, while the package-lock.json file specifies which versions *have been proven* to work. Through `npm update`, you can install the latest versions of packages, and (after testing) commit the new package-lock.json file to your repository. That way, you only need to modify package.json when adding packages, or updating to a new Major version (i.e. 1.x.x => 2.x.x).